# Autohotkey sending multiple "push-to-talk" keydown / keyup events

Tags: macros, keyboard, autohotkey

The situation is:  I'm using a combination of Teamspeak [shared communication], ARMA 2 with ACRE extension [Gaming software w/ extended "radio" capabilities] and DXTory [video and audio splitting/recording software].

The problem is: DXTory records audio when a single hotkey is pressed.  ACRE uses a set of hotkeys to allow switching between different radios.  I end up losing audio from "push-to-talk" keys that aren't monitored by DXTory.

What I'd like:  I'm thinking that autohotkey should allow me to take a "numpad-key-1" press and produce a "numpad-key-1" + "G3" (G3 being unused by ARMA/ACRE, but being used as the "push-to-talk" for DXTory and "numpad-key-1" being the push-to-talk for ARMA/ACRE).  Similarly, I'd map "numpad-key-2" to "numpad-key-2" + "G3" and "numpad-key-3" to "numpad-key-3" + "G3".

The G3 key would need to be key-down as the corresponding "numpad-key" is pressed and released with the key-up event.

Can this be done?  If so, any hints on how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is achieved quite simply. Repeat the code for in your script changing only the Numpad0-9 and possibly your "G3" key, I don't have one of those on my keyboard.

```
Numpad0::                           ;Declare your hotkey
    While GetKeyState("Numpad0")    ;Check key state
    {
        SendInput {G3 Down}         ;Set G3 as pressed 
    } 
    SendInput {G3 Up}               ;Set G3 as released 
return                              ;Return from function
```

Comment: This code seems semantically problematic. Intutively, it makes no sense to send `{KEY down}` more than once without sending a `{KEY up}`  in between. In other words, you can't push a key (more) down if it already is; at least not without breaking your keyboard. Why not just `Send {G3}` within the loop?